# Getting Errors trying to attach ua token

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-advantage, esm

I am trying to enable ESM on my 16.04 VPS server, but I am getting errors trying to connect to the canonical server. The error I am getting after running the ssh command `# sudo ua attach C122.....` is:

```
Failed to connect to authentication server
Check your Internet connection and try again.
Failed to access URL: https://contracts.canonical.com/v1/resources?kernel=4.4.0-1160.21.1.vz7.174.13&series=xenial&architecture=amd64
Cannot verify certificate of server
Please check your openssl configuration.
```

I read somewhere it could be `iptables` blocking it, but I have `OUTGOING` on `ACCEPT ALL`.
And when I ping https://canonical.com I get a healthy response.

Anybody have any idea?

---

Thank you for your help, @andrew-lowther. I did as you suggested. I could not post this lengthy result in a comment to your answer.

The ca-certicates were already at the latest version. The curl test seems fine also:

```
* Connected to contracts.canonical.com (91.189.92.69) port 443 (#0)
* found 129 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 520 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: contracts.canonical.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: CN=contracts.canonical.com
*        start date: Fri, 16 Jul 2021 18:50:43 GMT
*        expire date: Thu, 14 Oct 2021 18:50:41 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,O=Let's Encrypt,CN=R3
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: contracts.canonical.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
< Date: Sat, 24 Jul 2021 10:10:20 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 19
< Connection: keep-alive
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Trace-Id: 05087364-13c5-426f-9a59-99c7384f2dde
<
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host contracts.canonical.com left intact`
```

Does this give you any other clues?

Thanks again.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates the connection is allowed but your VPS server does not trust the Canonical server's certificate.

A good first step is to make sure the root certificates are up to date on your VPS server.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Using `curl` is a simple way to test.  If this command fails with output that includes `SSL certificate problem` then that would confirm the certificate issue.

```
curl -vs https://contracts.canonical.com
```

You can also use the `-k` option with `curl` to ignore certificate errors and learn more about what certificate the VPS server is receiving.

```
curl -vsk https://contracts.canonical.com -o /dev/null
```

**EDIT**

Your `curl` output does suggest that the Canonical server's certificate is trusted.  Your VPS server can reach the Canonical server and nothing appears to be interfering with the traffic.

These are a couple of other commands you can try, although they usually are not necessary to run manually.

```
update-ca-certificates
c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs
```

When I `strace` a `ua` command it appears to be specifically looking for the file `/usr/lib/ssl/certs/4042bcee.0`.  You can also verify this exists and is a symlink to the root certificate.  This symlink gets created by the `c_rehash` command.

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/ssl/certs/4042bcee.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Feb 19 14:09 /usr/lib/ssl/certs/4042bcee.0 -> ISRG_Root_X1.pem
```

**EDIT 2**

From your comment it sounds like the `/usr/lib/ssl/` directory may be messed up.  It should contain several symlinks

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/ssl/
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 15  2016 certs -> /etc/ssl/certs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 19 14:10 misc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Feb 17 10:21 openssl.cnf -> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 15  2016 private -> /etc/ssl/private
```

Comment: Thanks, @andrew-lowther. I executed the two commands, no change. 
I checked for the file /usr/lib/ssl/certs/4042bcee.0, but it does not exist.

Comment: @andrew-lowther, the file does exist at /etc/ssl/certs/4042bcee.0. I copied it to /usr/lib/ssl/certs/.., and executed the ua command and now it worked :) Don't know if that is the right procedure though. But thanks :)

Comment: @Tezalsec glad it is working.  I made one more edit to show what symlinks should exist in `/usr/lib/ssl` so that it the file only really needs to exist in `/etc/ssl/certs`

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes here with a failed certificate check when trying `curl -vs https://contracts.canonical.com` start with the instructions [here](https://www.codingmerc.com/blog/add-lets-encrypt-root-certificate-linux/)

The commands shown there are:

```
cd /usr/share/ca-certificates
sudo mkdir letsencrypt.org
cd letsencrypt.org/
wget "https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem"
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

That still didn't work for me. Seeing [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1353701/564673) that the certs folder holds the symlinks to the certificate files. I copied the file into `etc/ssl/certs` and  create a symlink to it. (The copying was probably unnecessary). Then I ran the update certificate command @Andrew had mentioned `c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs` which did the trick.