# Resolving SSL/TLS Connection Issues on Ubuntu 22.04 - issues with Dell Library

Tags: package-management, dell, ssl, ubuntu-pro

I was having some issues with SSL connections. It turns out OpenSSL was using libraries provided by Dell which caused compatability issues.

While trying to attach Ubuntu Pro, I encountered:

```
user@host:~$sudo pro attach *********************
Failed to connect to authentication server
Check your Internet connection and try again.
```

And while trying to initialize Waydroid I encountered an SSL error message.
I knew nothing was wrong with my network or the hosts I was trying to reach.

So I read in [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353643/getting-errors-trying-to-attach-ua-token) to try a few commands to diagnose and debug SSL issues, and namely this one gave me some useful debugging info

```
user@host:~$sudo c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs

Doing /etc/ssl/certs
/usr/bin/openssl: /opt/dell
/usr/bin/openssl: /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.3' not found (required by /usr/bin/openssl) 
# (this message on the above line repeated numerous times)
```

I then checked this per a recommendation I received.

```
user@host:~$ openssl version

openssl: /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.3' not found (required by openssl)
```

So there is an error related to a library provided by Dell. I have a Dell Latitude 5420.

I checked the library path to see where the libcrypto.so.3 library is being loaded from. Used the `ldd` command to inspect the dependencies of the openssl binary:

```
ubuntu@laptop-ubuntu22-04:~$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl

/usr/bin/openssl: /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.3' not found (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe945e0000)
    libssl.so.3 => /opt/dell/dcc/libssl.so.3 (0x00007fda47637000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007fda47000000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fda46c00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fda47632000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fda4762d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fda477f9000)
```

My output from ldd /usr/bin/openssl confirms that the OpenSSL binary is linking to the OpenSSL libraries provided by Dell in `/opt/dell/dcc/`. It seems that these libraries are not compatible with the expected version of OpenSSL.
To resolve this issue, I chose to make use of the system's OpenSSL libraries instead of the Dell-provided ones.

I removed the Dell-provided OpenSSL Libraries since they are causing conflicts, moving them to a backup copy folder to prevent them from being used by the system.

```
sudo mv /opt/dell/dcc /opt/dell/dcc_backup
```

After making directory changes, I updated the system's library cache to reflect the changes:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

However, I was still having SSL issues.

Checked my `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` config file to check for conflicts - none found.

So I reinstalled OpenSSL

```
sudo apt install --reinstall openssl
```

And updated my SSL certificate store

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

But still had errors and tried this

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

After all of this I was able to attach Ubuntu Pro and not have SSL issues in Waydroid. I don't anticipate further SSL issues I surely would have eventually uncovered also.

*I did have to reinstall Waydroid to get it to work right. Thankfully it was my first time using it so I had nothing to lose. Looking back, perhaps I could just have stopped and restarted the Waydroid service.*

Hopefully sharing this can help someone else out with a similiar issue...

Answer (score 0):

By redirecting OpenSSL to use Ubuntu's libraries, reinstalling OpenSSL and CA certificates, and updating CA certificates, I resolved the SSL/TLS connection issues. I have briefed the steps below

If your issue is as below - Dell-provided OpenSSL libraries causing conflicts:

```
openssl: /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.3' not found (required by openssl)
```

The solution seems to be:

-You should remove or rename them.

```
sudo mv /opt/dell/dcc /opt/dell/dcc_backup
```

-Redirect OpenSSL to Use Ubuntu's libraries instead of Dell's.

```
sudo ldconfig
```

-Reinstalling OpenSSL and updating CA Certificates

```
sudo apt install --reinstall openssl
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```