# Failed to attach machine. see https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard

Tags: ubuntu-pro

Our managed service provider built a new ubuntu server with 20.04 LTS.  I have been asked to apply the CIS benchmark profile for Level 1 Server to the server. I have an Ubuntu Pro account and I'm trying to attach my machine and getting the following error after running sud pro attach Token :

I've replaced the word Token with my actual token from the website. Error is below:

Failed to attach machine. see https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard

Any ideas ?  I tried the following suggestions:

[Getting Errors trying to attach ua token](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353643/getting-errors-trying-to-attach-ua-token/1353701#1353701)

sudo curl -vs https://contracts.canonical.com

- Trying 185.125.190.31:443...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to contracts.canonical.com (185.125.190.31) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
- TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
- TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
- TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
- TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
- SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
- Closing connection 0

sudo pro status
Failed to access URL: https://contracts.canonical.com/v1/resources?architecture=amd64&kernel=5.4.0-174-generic&series=focal&virt=vmware
Cannot verify certificate of server
Please check your openssl configuration.

Thanks,
Jimmy